# Convert PSTR to PWSTR and Escape Certain Characters

Tags: c, string, unicode, converters

I am trying to put together a function to convert a PSTR to a PWSTR and at the same time, escape certain characters at the same time. I have no control over the input PSTR contains. It can be the contents on any web page.

I have the following code already, but I was wondering if there is a better / more effecient way, or if what I have will even work.

```
__inline PCWSTR ToEscape(CHAR c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case '"':  return L"\"";
    case '\\': return L"\\";
    case '\b': return L"\b";
    case '\f': return L"\f";
    case '\n': return L"\n";
    case '\r': return L"\r";
    case '\t': return L"\t";
    default:   return NULL;
    }
}

// Helper for mbstowcs_s that does not return NULL terminator included in size
__inline DWORD CharToWChar(__out_ecount_opt(cchBuffer) WCHAR* pszBuffer, __in DWORD cchBuffer, __in_ecount(valueLen) PCSTR value, __in DWORD valueLen)
{
    if (valueLen == 0) return 0;

    size_t dwSize = 0;
    mbstowcs_s(&dwSize, pszBuffer, cchBuffer, value, valueLen);
    return dwSize - 1;
}

// Writes the input value to pszBuffer, or if pszBuffer is NULL, returns the length necessary to write value
__inline DWORD WriteJsonValue(__out_ecount_opt(cchBuffer) WCHAR* pszBuffer, __in DWORD cchBuffer, __in PCSTR value)
{
    if (pszBuffer == NULL)
    {
        DWORD offset = 2;

        PCSTR start = value;
        DWORD index = 0;
        while (value[index] != '\0')
        {
            PCWSTR Escape = ToEscape(value[index]);
            if (Escape)
            {
                offset += CharToWChar(NULL, 0, start, (value + index) - start);
                start = value + index + 1;
                offset += 2;
            }
            index++;
        }

        // Any more left to write?
        offset += CharToWChar(NULL, 0, start, (value + index) - start);

        return offset;
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD offset = 0;
        if (cchBuffer < 1) return 0;
        pszBuffer[offset++] = L'"';

        PCSTR start = value;
        DWORD index = 0;
        while (value[index] != '\0')
        {
            PCWSTR Escape = ToEscape(value[index]);
            if (Escape)
            {
                DWORD dwLen = (value + index) - start;
                offset += CharToWChar(pszBuffer+offset, cchBuffer-offset, start, dwLen);
                start = value + index + 1;

                if (cchBuffer < offset + 2) return offset;
                pszBuffer[offset++] = Escape[0];
                pszBuffer[offset++] = Escape[1];
            }
            index++;
        }

        // Any more left to write?
        DWORD dwLen = (value + index) - start;
        offset += CharToWChar(pszBuffer+offset, cchBuffer-offset, start, dwLen);

        if (cchBuffer < offset + 1) return offset;
        pszBuffer[offset++] = L'"';

        return offset;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with boost::nowide's "widen()"? (header-only). Or windows mbstowcs()? May I ask you why are you doing it at all? and, http://utf8everywhere.org is a good reference for this kind of tricks.

Comment: I can't use any non Windows APIs. The above was already using mbstowcs_s. The problem wasn't simply converting to wide characters, but efficiently escaping the necessary ones at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
__inline PCWSTR ToEscape(WCHAR c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case L'"':  return L"\"";
    case L'\\': return L"\\";
    case L'\b': return L"\b";
    case L'\f': return L"\f";
    case L'\n': return L"\n";
    case L'\r': return L"\r";
    case L'\t': return L"\t";
    default:   return NULL;
    }
}

__inline DWORD WriteEscapedCharacter(__out_ecount(cchBuffer) WCHAR* pszBuffer, __in DWORD cchBuffer, __in WCHAR value)
{
    PCWSTR Escape = ToEscape(value);
    if (Escape)
    {
        if (cchBuffer < 2) return 0;
        pszBuffer[0] = Escape[0];
        pszBuffer[1] = Escape[1];
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if (cchBuffer < 1) return 0;
        pszBuffer[0] = value;
        return 1;
    }
}

// Writes the input value to pszBuffer, or if pszBuffer is NULL, returns the length necessary to write value
__inline DWORD WriteJsonValue(__out_ecount_opt(cchBuffer) WCHAR* pszBuffer, __in DWORD cchBuffer, __in PCSTR value)
{
    size_t valueLen = _mbstrlen(value);

    if (pszBuffer == NULL)
    {
        DWORD offset = 2;

        WCHAR ch = 0;
        DWORD index = 0;
        while (index < valueLen)
        {
            DWORD chLen = mblen(value + index, valueLen - index);
            if (chLen < 1) break;
            mbtowc(&ch, value + index, chLen);
            offset += ToEscape(ch) ? 2 : 1;
            index += chLen;
        }

        return offset;
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD offset = 0;
        if (cchBuffer < 1) return 0;
        pszBuffer[offset++] = L'"';

        WCHAR ch = 0;
        DWORD index = 0;
        while (value[index] != '\0')
        {
            DWORD chLen = mblen(value + index, valueLen - index);
            if (chLen < 1) break;
            mbtowc(&ch, value + index, chLen);
            offset += WriteEscapedCharacter(pszBuffer + offset, cchBuffer - offset, value[index]);
            index += chLen;
        }

        if (cchBuffer < offset + 1) return offset;
        pszBuffer[offset++] = L'"';

        return offset;
    }
}
```